# Substitute text in html table generated with angularjs with icon on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a html page that contains a table with date, staffID and shift. Shift has a value of 0 (morning) or 1 (afternoon).  It is generated as follows:

```js
function staffSchedule ($scope, $http) {
  $http
    .get('/api/schedule/2017/02')
    .then(function(response) {
      var data = response.data;
      $scope.shifts = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function(errorResponse) {
      console.log('Error: ' + errorResponse.status);
    });
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>StaffID</th>
    <th>Shift</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody ng-repeat="shift in shifts">
    <tr>
      <td>{{shift.staffid}}</td>
      <td>{{shift.date}}</td>
      <td>{{shift.type}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The code returns the data as it should do but I want to extend it to do something more.

I want the code to dynamically substitute the 0 for Fontawesome sun  `<i class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>` and 1 for Fontawesome moon `<i class="fa fa-moon-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>`. Any idea how I can do this with my current setup please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did in my code to get it to work.

```
<td>
  <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-hourglass-start':schedule.shift==0,
                           'fa-hourglass-end':schedule.shift==1}">
  </i>
</td>
```

To explain:

1. Grab my icons from font awesome http://fontawesome.io/
2. ng-repeat receives requests from a RESTful call via AngularJS
3. one of the fields in the record returns '0' or '1' (always; required field)
4. Use fa-hourglass-start if 0 and fa-hourglas-end if 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Something like:

```
<td>
    <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-sun':shift.type==0,'fa-moon':shift.type==1}"></i>
</td>
```

Note I did not verify the proper FA class names